# How to play music if any silent push fired in background mode in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Currently I am working on a project which requires to play music if any silent push fired in background mode.How can it be done in objective c? Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo{
    SystemSoundID soundID;
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef)@"yourSoundFile", NULL, NULL);
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```